# ZeroMQ: how to reduce multithread-communication latency with inproc?

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, zeromq, latency

I'm using `inproc` and `PAIR` to achieve inter-thread communication and trying to solve a latency problem due to polling. Correct me if I'm wrong: Polling is inevitable, because a plain `recv()` call will usually block and cannot take a specific timeout.

In my current case, among N threads, each of the `N-1` worker threads has a main while-loop. The N-th thread is a  controller thread which will notify all the worker threads to quit at any time. However, worker threads have to use polling with a timeout to get that `quit` message. This introduces a latency, the latency parameter is usually `1000ms`.

Here is an example

```cpp
while (true) {
    const std::chrono::milliseconds nTimeoutMs(1000);
    std::vector<zmq::poller_event<std::size_t>> events(n);  
    size_t nEvents = m_poller.wait_all(events, nTimeoutMs); 
    bool isToQuit = false;
    for (auto& evt : events) {
        zmq::message_t out_recved;
        try {
            evt.socket.recv(out_recved, zmq::recv_flags::dontwait);
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) {
            trace("{}: Caught exception while polling: {}. Skipped.", GetLogTitle(), e.what());
            continue;
        }
        if (!out_recved.empty()) {
            if (IsToQuit(out_recved))
               isToQuit = true;
               break;
        }
    }
    if (isToQuit)
       break;
    //
    // main business
    //
    ...
}
```

To make things worse, when the main loop has nested loops, the worker threads then need to include more polling code in each layer of the nested loops. Very ugly.

The reason why I chose ZMQ for multithread communication is because of its elegance and the potential of getting rid of thread-locking. But I never realized the polling overhead.

Am I able to achieve the typical latency when using a regular mutex or an `std::atomic` data operation? Should I understand that the `inproc` is in fact a network communication pattern in disguise so that some latency is inevitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An above posted statement ( *a hypothesis* ):

> *"...a plain `recv()` call **will** usually **block and cannot take a specific timeout."***

is not correct:
a plain `.recv( ZMQ_NOBLOCK )`-call will never ***"block"***,
a plain `.recv( ZMQ_NOBLOCK )`-call can get decorated so as to mimick ***"a specific timeout"***

An above posted statement ( *a hypothesis* ):

> "...***have*** to use polling with a timeout ... *introduces a latency, the latency parameter is usually **1000ms**.*"

is not correct:
- one need not use polling with a timeout
- the less one need not set 1000 ms code-"injected"-latency, spent obviously only on-no-new-message state

> **Q** : *"Am I able to achieve the typical latency when using a regular `mutex` or an `std::atomic` data operation?"*

Yes.

> **Q** : *"Should I understand that the `inproc` is in fact a network communication pattern in disguise so that some latency is inevitable?"*

No. **`inproc`**-transport-class is the fastest of all these kinds as it is principally protocol-less / stack-less and has more to do with ultimately fast pointer-mechanics, like in a dual-end ring-buffer pointer-management.

---

### The Best Next Step:

**1 )**
Re-factor your code, so as to always harness but the zero-wait **`{ .poll() | .recv() }`**-methods, properly decorated for both { event- | no-event- }-specific looping.

**2 )**
If **then** willing to shave the last few `[us]` from the smart-loop-detection turn-around-time, may focus on improved **`Context()`**-instance setting it to work with larger amount of `nIOthreads > N` "under the hood".

**optionally 3 )**
For almost hard-Real-Time systems' design one may **finally** harness a deterministically driven `Context()`-threads' and socket-specific mapping of these execution-vehicles onto specific, non-overlapped CPU-cores ( using a carefully-crafted affinity-map )

---

Having set 1000 [ms] in code, no one is fair to complain about spending those very 1000 [ms] waiting in a timeout, coded by herself / himself. No excuse for doing this.

Do not blame ZeroMQ for behaviour, that was coded from the application side of the API.

Never.

Comment: Thanks. This is somewhat a relieve. In the beginning, I tried poll with the default `-1` timeout, which could block forever, then a few milliseconds seem to always miss until I used `1000ms`. Just tried polling with `0ms` timeout and it works.